# Как запустить FirebaseMessagingService после закрытие приложение?

Tags: android, firebase, service, уведомления

Необходимо чтобы `FirebaseMessagingService()` работал когда приложение закрыто.

Тут указывают: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50238790, что

> когда приложение находится в разработке, если вы принудительно закроете приложение (kill-process), `FirebaseMessagingService` перестанет запускаться

Я попробовал `release`, подписав его, не сработало.

В `service` указал `android:exported="true"`, не работает.

Прочел, что можно перезапустить с помощью `alarm`, сделал как указали, не работает.
(и в `onDestroy()`) и в самом сервисе в `onTaskRemoved`).

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить эту проблему...?

Comment: После убийства процесса приложение можно лишь вручную запустить, на иконку нажав. Так уж Андроид работает. Спасает батарею девайса от постоянно работающих приложений

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том что он жизненным циклом `FirebaseMessagingSerive` управляют только сами Google Services, и мы не имеем к этому доступа.

Не важно запущенно приложение, или нет, гугл сервисы сами запустят твой сервис на обработку в случае, если пришло какое-то сообщение из Firebase (и потом сервис прибьется через несколько секунд уже самим Android, чтобы сохранить батарею)

Таким образом, не управляя жизненным циклом, наш сервис будет работать всегда, и только когда это нужно.